# jquery ui autocomplete - open event (handling no results)

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I wanted to use the open event to return "no results found" when ui == null but in firebug it looks like that even after the open event is fired the ui list is always empty even if there are results.

My source is an XML file

I'm attempting:

```
open: function(event,ui) {
  if( ui.item == null ) {
  console.log("no results");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to autocomplete.js:

```
    if(retMatch.length == 0) {
        var noResult = new Array();
        noResult[0] = {
        label: "No results found",
        title: "No results found",
        description: "Your search did not return any results. Please refine your search criteria. If you believe this message is in error please fill out a support case."
        }
        return noResult;
    }
```

to: 
`$.extend`

Comment: Doesn't this result in the "Now results founds" item in the drop-down to remain selectable?  Seems like you'll also want to inject yourself into __renderMenu and make it not selectable when the result is "No results found"